# Wrong doi link with htlatex --> biber --> htlatex

Tags: biblatex, htlatex

When compiling the following MWE with pdflatex --> biber --> pdflatex, a correct doi link is generated:

```
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002
```

However, when compiling with htlatex --> biber --> htlatex, an incomplete (and hence wrong) doi link is generated:

```
10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002
```

When having a closer look at the generated html file, it turns out that the correct link is overwritten by the incomplete (wrong) link:

```
<a href="https://doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002" ><a 
href="10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002" class="url" ><span 
class="cmtt-10">10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002</span></a></a>.
```

This, serious issue, produces wrong links in a file with multiple entries.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}   
@Article{b,
  date =     2003,
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journal},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002},
  pages =    {100-141}}   
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}   
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue here is that `htlatex` produces an `href` even for `\nolinkurl` (which should not produce a link as the name suggests) as soon as `biblatex` is loaded: https://gist.github.com/moewew/a3744249ad6f3b469e743c2a6e38181f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `\nolinkurl` is redefined to `\url` by TeX4ht. In this case, `\nolinkurl` is used by Biblatex to print just part of DOI and `\href` outputs the full address. This results in double link, where the partial link that doesn't point anywhere is contained in the correct link. Unfortunately, the wrong link is picked by browser. To workaround this, you can save the original meaning of `\nolinkurl` and override the TeX4ht configuration.

Try this config file:

```
\let\orignolinkurl\nolinkurl
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
\let\nolinkurl\orignolinkurl
```

It produces a better output:

```html
<p class='noindent'><a id='cite.0@b'></a>Amy Author. “Title”. In: <span class='cmti-10'>Journal </span>10.4 (2003), pp. 100–141. <span class='cmcsc-10'><span class='small-caps'>doi</span></span>: <a href='https://doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.06.002'><span class='cmtt-10'>10.1016/
    </span><span class='cmtt-10'>j.automatica.2013.06.002</span></a>.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @michal.h21. It works great! Is this just a workaround and the issue will be corrected in an upcoming version of TeX4ht?

Comment: @rasha this is already fixed in TeX4ht sources, so it should be available in TeX Live soon.